# Different result on converting date from string in iOS 13 and iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having troubles on converting Date from string on iOS 11.4. Same func on iOS 11.4 is returning nil, but in iOS 13 returns correct value.
I'm using Xcode 11.0, and this convert func:

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromStringDate:(NSString *)stringDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"];
    return [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];
}
```

Comment: And what is `stringDate`?

Comment: is date in this format: 2020-01-13T10:39:56+01:00

Comment: Also just to make things more complicated your original code works fine for me on iOS 11 simulator. So I can't even reproduce the issue.

Comment: Actually your time zone is probably `XXXXX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSISO8601DateFormatter knows more and is more flexible than any format string you can write. Rewrite your code as

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateFromStringDate:(NSString *)stringDate {
    NSISO8601DateFormatter * df = [NSISO8601DateFormatter new];
    return [df dateFromString:stringDate];
}
```